# How can I use IOS Emulator on Smartface?

Tags: ios, emulation, publish, smartface.io

I want to test my app on smartface but I dont have licence. Do you know anyway for test it ? I saw a video on youtube and he maked somethings on itool and I tried samethings but its not working. Do you have any idea ? Its so important, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use iOS emulator, you should have at least an individual licence. 
You can check this link about pricing : https://account.smartface.io/License/

If you have a Mac, you can use iOS publish. You will get publish with Smartface on Windows, and then open this publish with xCode on Mac.

By the way, Android emulator is available for every user.

Comment: Merve hanim ios emulatoru kisitlamaniz programin yayilmasini ciddi derecede engellemekte sahsimca, tam aradigim gibi bir program buldum diye sevinirken ios emulatorun ucretli paketlerde bulunmasi hayallerimi suya dusurdu. En azindan bir haftalik vs test etme sansimiz olsaydi hosuma gitse zaten satin alirdim :)